# Validity of geometric series expressed as polynomial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

This is my first question so I may not be the best at the correct language format and professionalism. First year college student in Calc 2.

I believe that within determining the convergence and divergence of series, all the unique types of functions ($x^{n}$, n, x, ln(n), etc.) could be "mirrored" (expressed as another function) into the function $n^{x}$, where x varies based on a set of equations. I've slowly been working my way through mathematically proving this, and this question is about whether what I have found is valid or not. While this is useless for knowing what a series converges to, it is excellent in determining if the series will converge or diverge.

I believe that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)x^{n}$ (where $f\left(x\right)$ is any function) can be "mirrored" into $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{A}$, given that $f\left(x\right)$ is NOT $X^{n}$ (where if $(-1<x<0)$ or $(0<x<1)$, then $(X<-1)$ or $(X>1)$ ), n!, or $n^{n}$.

x here is equal to the fraction $\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}$, and A can be one of three numbers depending on what x is:

1. A is equal to $-\infty$ if $0<\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}<1$ or $-1<\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}<0$
2. A is equal to $0$ if $\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}=1$ or $\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}=-1$
3. A is equal to $\infty$ if $1<\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}$ or $\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}<-1$

This idea works by utilizing 2 methods of determining convergence, those being:

1. Test for divergence, in which the function(s) in the series have their n replaced with $\infty$, and if the result is not infinity, the series converges
2. Ratio Test, which is given by the function $lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|$, where if the result is less than $1$, the series converges, but if greater than $1$, the series diverges.

The main connection between $x^{n}$ and $n^{A}$ and how they can mirror each other is based on how both functions act when n is $\infty$.

1. $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}$ converges by geometric series test, and $n^{-\infty}$ also converges because at any value n larger than 1, it becomes $\frac{1}{n^{\infty}}$ and any value larger than 1 to the power of infinity also becomes infinity.
2. $\left(1\right)^{n}$ diverges because 1 to any power will equal 1, and the sum of 1 to infinity is infinity. $n^{0}$ diverges because any value n to the power of 0 becomes 1, and as previously stated, the sum of 1 to infinity is infinity.
3. $2^{n}$ and $n^{\infty}$ both diverge because at n=infinity, both are infinite.

Quick note before work is shown: if the function $\left(\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}\right)^{-n}$ is given, it acts inverted, but can be fixed by replacing it with the function $\left(\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}\right)^{n}$ before mirroring.

With all the unique types of functions, there's an imaginary "value" within each function I call "strength", which is the hidden key to determining convergence. It works by comparing the rates at which simple functions grow compared to each other, and to keep it simple, here's a short list of "strength" from strongest to weakest [their mirrored value]:

$n^{n}\left[n^{\infty^{\infty}}\right]$, $n!\left[n^{\infty^{2}}\right]$, $a^{n}\left\{given\ a>1\right\}\left[n^{\infty}\right]$, $\log_{a}\left(n\right)\left[?,\ but\ between\ 0\ and\ 1\right]$, $(a,a^{n})\left\{given\ a=1\right\}\left[n^{0}\right]$, alternating functions such as $\left(-1\right)^{n}\ or\ \cos\left(\pi n\right)\ \left[usually\ n^{-1}\right]$, and lastly $a^{n}\left\{given\ a<1\right\}\left[n^{-\infty}\right]$

When looking at a fraction within a summation, if there is a function with a higher "strength" in the numerator, that function will ALWAYS diverge, but having a higher strength in the denominator requires mirroring all the functions and comparing the highest power in the numerator and denominator to determine convergence, where the value of the highest power in the denominator - the highest power in the numerator must be greater than 1 to converge.

Lastly, here are some equations showing why some equations are stronger than others, specifically why $x^{n}$ is stronger than $n^{x}$ for all values x (except n), but is weaker than $n^{n}$:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\ \to\ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}}{n^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}\right|\to\ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(n+1\right)}{n^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}\right|\to$$

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\ \right)limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\left(n\right)}}{n^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}\right|\ \to\left(\ \frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\ \right)\ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n}}{n^{n}}\right|\to\ \left(\ \frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\ \right)\ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}\right|\to$$

$$\left(\ \frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\ \right)\ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right|\ \to\left(\ \frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\ \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\infty}\right)^{\infty}\ \to\ \left(\ \frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\ \right)\left(1+0\right)^{\infty}\ \to\ \left(\ \frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\ \right)\left(1\right)^{\infty}\ \to\ $$

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1\right)\ \to\ \frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\to\frac{1}{2}\infty+\frac{1}{2}\to\infty\ \to\ diverges\ by\ ratio\ test$$

Assume $\left(\frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}\ \right)$ was placed between the limit and absolute value sign, I kind of messed up the formatting, but the solution remains the same.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{1000000}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\to\ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{1000000}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}}{n^{1000000}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}\right|\to\ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{1000000}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{n^{1000000}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}\right|\to$$

$$limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{1000000}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}{n^{1000000}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}\right|\ \right)\to\ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{1000000}}{n^{1000000}}\right|\right)\to\ \ limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left|\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{1000000}\right)\right|\to$$

$$limit\left(n\to\infty\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\left|\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1000000}\right|\right)\ \to\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\infty}\right)^{1000000}\ \to\ \frac{1}{2}\ \left(1+0\right)^{1000000}\ \to\ \frac{1}{2}\to converges\ by\ ratio\ test\ $$

The main issue I have found with this theorem is that when using certain tests, specifically the one right above this, that 1,000,000 can actually be replaced with infinity (which is also our n), and would still satisfy the summation as converging, yet if our value "x" is replaced with n, it diverges. I'd assume it has something to do with setting "x" to a sort of "fixed" infinity, while n is a "continuous" infinity.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback or instances my theory doesn't work, since my professor actually encouraged me to come here and share my idea.

Comment: I will not enter into the detail of your serious work but the general idea to connect $x^n$ to $n^x$ looks non-natural to me because these functions have a so different nature... for example (n+1)nd derivative = 0 for the first one whereas the second is infinitely derivable...

Comment: You can obtain $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ by typing `$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$`.